# while loop won't terminate even if i input a zero value for a and b

Tags: while-loop, do-while

```
    do
    {
        scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
        stcrnrArray[x] = a;
        ++a;
        stcrnrArray[x] = b;
        ++b;
    }
    while((a != 0) && (b != 0));
```

while loop won't terminate even if i input a zero value for a and b

Comment: In what context you are using this loop?? Do while execute atleast one time and initializing both variable to 0, condition in while will always be true since you incremented the variables.

Comment: edit your tags and add the language you are using

Answer (score 0):

What is question? it will not terminate because u have given ++a; so its pre incrementing everytime thats why at the end (a != 0) condition satisfies..

Answer (score 0):

if a = -1 and b = -1  the loop terminate